# onclick Event Not Running on HTML Select Drop Down

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a HTML select drop down with six options all I'm trying to achieve is when the option "Other" is selected a javascript alert appears, but for some reason I cannot get this to work.

I've tried moving the onclick to the select tag rather than the option tag, and moving the alert outside the parameters which allows it to appear as soon as the drop down is clicked which worked but isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

```js
function otherPayment() {
  var paymentType = document.getElementById("paymentType").value;
  if (paymentType == "Other") {
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="paymentType">Payment Type:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="paymentType" name="paymentType" required>
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="Payment (Initial)">Payment (Initial)</option>
    <option value="Payment (Full)">Payment (Full)</option>
    <option value="Payment (Balance)">Payment (Balance)</option>
    <option value="Delivery Fee">Delivery</option>
    <option onclick="otherPayment()" value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `onchange` on the `select` tag not on the `option` tag.

```js
function otherPayment() {
  var paymentType = document.getElementById("paymentType").value;
  if (paymentType == "Other") {
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="paymentType">Payment Type:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="paymentType" name="paymentType" required onchange="otherPayment()">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="Payment (Initial)">Payment (Initial)</option>
    <option value="Payment (Full)">Payment (Full)</option>
    <option value="Payment (Balance)">Payment (Balance)</option>
    <option value="Delivery Fee">Delivery</option>
    <option  value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The `onclick` trigger will trigger when the select is clicked, as well as when an option is chosen.

Comment: Fantastic thanks I didn't realize I needed to use `onchange`, I'll mark this as the correct answer once the time parameters allow me to. Thanks again.

Comment: It won't change the value, he is trying to change the value, after changing options so onclick won't work

Answer (score 5):

`<option>` elements don't behave like normal HTML elements, so `onclick` doesn't do anything.

The easiest way to do this is to use the `onchange` event of the select, and then inspect the newly selected element, like this:

```js
function handlePaymentChange(event) {
  var paymentType = event.target.value;
  if (paymentType == "Other") {
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="paymentType">Payment Type:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="paymentType" name="paymentType" required onchange="handlePaymentChange(event)">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="Payment (Initial)">Payment (Initial)</option>
    <option value="Payment (Full)">Payment (Full)</option>
    <option value="Payment (Balance)">Payment (Balance)</option>
    <option value="Delivery Fee">Delivery</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use `onselect`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="paymentType">Payment Type:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="paymentType" name="paymentType" onselect="otherPayment()" required>
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="Payment (Initial)">Payment (Initial)</option>
    <option value="Payment (Full)">Payment (Full)</option>
    <option value="Payment (Balance)">Payment (Balance)</option>
    <option value="Delivery Fee">Delivery</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Since there is already an `if/else`, it should work well.

Comment: Didn't know about this, nice one!

Comment: I think `onclick` would trigger before anything was selected...let me check

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to bind the **onchange** event of the drop down instead of **click** event of the option.

```
 <select class="form-control" id="paymentType" onchange="otherPayment()" name="paymentType" required>
```